# Component routing in a single page app Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular6

I am using Angular 6 and have 4 components in my project. I want to add all these components in a single page and I want the correct menu item to be active and the url changes to the correct route when i scroll to different components in the single page. I've been struggling with this and any help is much appreciated.

This is my header.component.html

```
    <section class="module-small navbar-light">
<mdb-navbar  SideClass="navbar fixed-top navbar-custom navbar-expand-lg scrolling-navbar ie-nav" [containerInside]="false">
  <logo class="logo">
    <img src="./assets/images/phf-logo.png" />
  </logo>
  <links class="links">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-flex-icons">
      <li class="nav-item active waves-light" mdbRippleRadius [ngClass]="{'green-text': activeMenu=='about'}" routerLink="/about"
       (click)="scroll(about,'about')">
        <a class="nav-link">ABOUT<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item waves-light" mdbRippleRadius [ngClass]="{'green-text': activeMenu=='features'}" routerLink="/features" (click)="scroll(features,'features')">
        <a class="nav-link">FEATURES</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item waves-light" mdbRippleRadius [ngClass]="{'green-text': activeMenu=='management'}" routerLink="/management" (click)="scroll(management,'management')">
        <a class="nav-link">MANAGEMENT</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item waves-light" mdbRippleRadius [ngClass]="{'green-text': activeMenu=='contact'}" routerLink="/contact"
      (click)="scroll(contact,'contact')" (scroll)="scrollHandler($event)">
        <a class="nav-link">CONTACT</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </links>
</mdb-navbar>
</section>

<div class="text-center">
  <div #about>
    <app-about></app-about>
  </div>
  <div #features>
    <app-features></app-features>
  </div>
  <div #management>
    <app-management></app-management>
  </div>
  <div #contact>
    <app-contact></app-contact>
  </div>
</div>
```

Header.component.ts

```
  scroll(el,name) {
this.activeMenu = name;
this.el =el;
el.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start'  });
```

}

This above function lets me scroll to the correct div when the menu item has been clicked.

The problem is: 
1) I am unable to change the menu to active when i scroll to a different component on the same page.
2) The URL does not change.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to trigger or call the method when the component position reaches to specific location.

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Input , ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appTrackScroll]'
})
export class TrackScrollDirective {


  @Input("appTrackScroll")
  private scrollName; 

   state = 'hide'

  constructor(public el: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
    checkScroll() {
      const componentPosition = this.el.nativeElement.offsetTop
      const scrollPosition = window.pageYOffset
       // You can set the position as per your rquirement.
      if (scrollPosition >= componentPosition) {
        // Enable the menu
      } else {
        // Disable the menu
      }

    }
}
```

Sample demo is here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zej55w

Comment: Gave this a shot and unfortunately, it does not seem to work for me. What I am trying to accomplish is to find which div I am on while scrolling.

Comment: This directive can be used in all four component like `[appTrackScroll]="'Menu One'"`. If see closely we are passing the name `Menu One` also.

Comment: Yes, So I went ahead and added [appTrackScroll]="About'" in the about.html, [appTrackScroll]="'Contact'" in the contact.html page etc.

When i scroll my page this is the output i get:

scrollPosition----- 28.88888931274414  Menu name  contact
track-scroll.directive.ts:19 scrollPosition----- 31.111112594604492  Menu name  About
track-scroll.directive.ts:19 scrollPosition----- 31.111112594604492  Menu name  contact
track-scroll.directive.ts:19 scrollPosition----- 33.333335876464844  Menu name  About

Comment: Updated the code in the link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zej55w